# SaveFileDialog instead of hardcoding save direction

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, savefiledialog

Ok, I've made it this far, but now I'm sort of stuck.

I have created a windows form that saves and loads student grades. Problem is that the save and load direction is hard coded, i want to use a filedialog to save and load the files.

I'm not exacly sure how to do that. Any ideas?

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\Users\grades.txt";
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(filePath);
            txtResult.AppendText(stream.ReadToEnd());
            lblStatus.Text = "File Loaded";
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("There was a problem loading the file");
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = "Entry saved";//shows in status label

        //string that specifies the location of the .txt file
         string filePath = @"C:\Users\grades.txt";

         StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath, true);//creates new object of class StreamWriter to be able to write to file

        //enters the information from the different textboxes to the file
        fileWriter.WriteLine(txtLastName.Text + ", " + txtFirstName.Text + ":\t" + Convert.ToString(txtID.Text) +
            "\t" + txtClass.Text + "\t" + txtGrades.Text);

        fileWriter.Close();//closes filewriter

    }

}
```

Edit:
New code with improvements (I haven't implemented Aybe's suggestions yet).

I think I'm kind of retarded but why isn't this working? In my mind this should work, but it doesn't. When i try to load file nothing happens...

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication14
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

        dlg.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        dlg.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        dlg.FilterIndex = 2;
        dlg.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return;

    }


    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Stream myStream;
            if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(myStream);//creates new object of class StreamWriter to be able to write to file

                //enters the information from the different textboxes to the file
                fileWriter.WriteLine(txtLastName.Text + ", " + txtFirstName.Text + ":\t" + Convert.ToString(txtID.Text) +
                    "\t" + txtClass.Text + "\t" + txtGrades.Text);

                fileWriter.Close();//closes filewriter
                myStream.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

[Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) dialogs are actually quite easy.

First, You'll initialize the dialog:

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"  ;
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 ;
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;
```

Then, you'll show it and wait for the user to navigate to their path and type a file name:

```
if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         if((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
         {
             // Code to write the stream goes here.
             myStream.Close();
         }
     }
```

Comment: Care to explain the down votes on mine and Aybe's answers?

Answer (score -1):

In addition to @bwoogie answer, leverage the `using` keyword to dispose of resources easily:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                if (dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
                    return;

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(dialog.OpenFile()))
                {
                    // TODO read file
                }
            }
        }

        private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var dialog = new SaveFileDialog())
            {
                if (dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
                    return;

                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(dialog.OpenFile()))
                {
                    // TODO save file
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```